# ¿Cuál es el significado de *this dentro de un constructor en C++?

Tags: c++, clase, punteros

Soy nuevo en C++, sé un poco de clases y de punteros pero no he podido entender este código
Si tengo dos constructores como en el siguiente código:

```
class Clase1
{
    public:
           Clase1()
           {
              *this = Clase1(2, 4);
           } 
          Clase1(int a, int b)
           {
              c = a + b;
           }
           int c;
}
```

¿Cuál es el significado de la expresión *this = Clase1(2, 4)?
¿Por qué *this *está guardando* un valor cuando se llama al otro constructor?
Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tenés un objeto y usas uno de sus métodos (o el constructor), dentro de ese
método `this` apunta a ese objeto.

Al hacer:

```
*this = Clase1(2, 4);
```

Pasa lo siguiente:

- Se crea un objeto temporal de clase `Clase1` usando el constructor con la signatura
  `Clase1(int a, int b)`.
- Se desreferencia el puntero `this`.
- Se ejecuta el *operador de asignación*, que por defecto copia miembro a miembro
  un objeto a otro, en este caso el objeto temporal al objeto que apunta `this`.
  Entonces `this->c` pasa a tener el mismo valor que el `c` del objeto temporal.

Podes comprobarlo implementando el *operador de asignación* con el comportamiento
por defecto para esta clase:

```
#include <iostream>

class Clase1
{
    public:

    int c;

    Clase1()
    {
        *this = Clase1(2, 4);
    }

    Clase1(int a, int b)
    {
        c = a + b;
    }

    Clase1& operator=(const Clase1& derecha) {
        std::cout << "Asignandole " << derecha.c
                  << " al `c` del objeto de la izquierda\n";

        c = derecha.c;

        return *this;
    }
};

int main() {
    Clase1 objeto;
    Clase1 otro{2, 4};

    std::cout << "objeto.c == " << objeto.c << '\n';
    std::cout << "otro.c == " << otro.c << '\n';
}
```

Y al ejecutarlo muestra:

```
Asignandole 6 al `c` del objeto de la izquierda
objeto.c == 6
otro.c == 6
```

---

Con respecto a la utilidad, sirve para no repetir código, delegando la
construcción del objeto a otro constructor. Al final tenes un objeto inicializado
de la misma forma que si hubieras usado el otro constructor.

Dentro del método `operator=`, `derecha` es el objeto `Clase1(2, 4)` luego de
ser inicializado por el constructor que recibe dos enteros. Lo único que hace
es pasar el miembro `c` (que fue inicializado por el otro constructor) al objeto
actual, que en este caso es el `*this` del constructor sin parametros.

Desde C++11, se puede usar otra sintáxis más sencilla que hace lo mismo pero
no usa `this` y tampoco el operador de asignación:

```
class Clase1() {
    public:

    Clase1(int a, b) {
        // ...
    }

    Clase1() : Clase1(2, 4) {
    }
}
```

Comment: aún no me queda muy claro lo de "operador de asignación"  en Clase1& operator=(const Clase1& derecha). Ni tampoco el código dentro de esa función. ¿qué utilidad tiene crear un objeto temporal usando *this? ¿porqué no crear un objeto temporal sin usar *this?

Comment: @SRG ahí edite mi respuesta

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder mis dudas. Saludos